# Transformation of security model written in own DSL-xtext

Tags: java, xtext, activiti, xtend, xpand

I've a security engineering model of business processes written in own DSL using xtext editor. 
For example, I've a security model for Activiti which has security controls e.g. securing transmission channel, encrypt message among processes, user access control etc. 
What I want to do is to write some implementation which will get that myfile.mydsl, parse it and automatically secure the environment (Activiti) i.e. configure server.xml of tomcat in tomcat for SSL, create keystore using keytool etc (Hence channel is secured).

It isn't a model to model transformation so ATL-eclipse might not be helpful. Will xpand-eclipse help because xpand does model to text transformation?

I was also thinking to generate XMI from xtext and parse it in java and do the implementation.
Does xtext editor provide some other way to parse the DSL to be helpful in implementation?

If my post is ambiguous then I can explain more.

Thanks in anticipation.

best regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to create an intermediate XMI serialized form of your model. If that one is loaded into memory, the object graph is pretty much the same as the one that you get from your Xtext DSL anyway. I'd recommend to use [Xtend](http://www.xtend-lang.org) to implement the code generator.

Comment: I actually couldn't get how it can be helpful for me as I never used it. Actually my problem is that I don't want to implement the code generator for the DSL grammar but the security model written using that DSL in eclipse editor e.g. myfile.myDSL and this security model should be parsed and implementation must be done for the myfile.myDSL taking it as input. Can you guide me a bit more? Thanks